# Reallocating pointers of pointers of pointers

Tags: c

As a part of our Computer Science course (using C), we are to build a VERY wasteful system using pointers
Since we are not allowed to use structures at this point, we are to use ONLY pointers for our dynamic-arrays.

I have created the dynamic-array **students and allocated space for it.
at this point, i send this dynamic array (**students) to a function that sends it to ANOTHER function (i send &students so i can change them by address)

My problem is, that i do not know (apparently - and after many many tries) how to reallocate space to this dynamic-array

To be specific, since i sent the array 2 times:
my first function receives ***students
and my second function receives ****students

I tried to reallocate space the following way (I am in the SECOND function at the moment)

```
*students = (char**)realloc(*students, 2 * sizeof(char*));
*students[1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char))
```

this seemed like the way to do it - apparently i was wrong
any help would be thankfully received :)

Edit:

The program will run if I do this:

```
**students = (char**)realloc(**students, 2 * sizeof(char*));
```

but then I am not able to use malloc correctly..

I would appreciate the understanding behind my question and not just a solution, so I can learn for next trial.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: Note that being a three-star programmer is not a compliment in C. What would that make a four-star programmer?

Comment: See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FiveStarProgrammer There's always a bigger fish.

Comment: As you would see, I did mention this program is not the brightest in use.
but... I still need to finish it.

Comment: Respectfully, Olaf... I don't care for compliments as a programmer at this point :)

Comment: There are many ways to use `malloc` and `realloc`. It depends on what exactly you want to allocate, but you haven't really said that. e.g. do you want a 1D/2D/3D array, how many elements in each dimension, what type it contains, etc.

Comment: Hey interjay, at this point, i only want to allocate the space so i can even put a char there... since i use some other functions and reallocation before this point - i have decided that -maybe- mentioning all of that would only confuse... i need a 2D array (D1 are pointers and D2 are strings)

Comment: What do you mean by *send*? And why does "sending" a second time add another indirection? Could you please use common C terminolgy and rephrase the whole question? As-is it is next to impossible to understand.

Comment: I am sorry, since i have only coded in C for a month, I guess the terminology used is blurred... by "sending" i mean that i do "scan_strings_from_user(char*** students)" sending a second time means that I'll do "String_Exists(char ****students, char** newString)" I hope this clarifies thigs

Comment: You should always reallocate pointers of pointers of pointers to the garbage bin.

Comment: I don't understand the question... Your task is to make a bad program and now you have made a program which doesn't work. Success.

Comment: Do yourself a favour, and use `sizeof *ptr_to_allocate` instead of `sizeof(type)`. That way, you're far more likely to allocate enough memory: `char ***foo = malloc(10 * sizeof *foo);` vs `malloc(10 * sizeof(char**));` which is easier to read? (if you insist on using triple indirection anyways)

Comment: I think this is a good time to ask the OP for a minmal (1) specification and (2) as complete as possible (but still minimal!) code example of what he wants to achieve, together with the build- or run time errors. That is, use the simplest data possible (int or char) and the simplest data structure that you fail to understand or design or code. For example, my assumption is that if you cannot allocate and pass around data for a 2-dimensional matrix you will also have trouble with a simple one-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created the dynamic-array **students and allocated space for
>   it. at this point, i send this dynamic array (**students) to a
>   function that sends it to ANOTHER function (i send &students so i can
>   change them by address)
>   …
>   To be specific, since i sent the array 2 times: my first function
>   receives ***students and my second function receives ****students

There is no sense in taking the array pointer's address (i. e. `&students`) more than once, since we then already have the means to reallocate the array:

```
void ANOTHER_function(char ***students)
{
    *students = realloc(*students, 2 * sizeof **students);  // room for 2 char *
    (*students)[1] = malloc(sizeof *(*students)[1]);        // room for 1 char
}

void a_function(char ***students)
{
    ANOTHER_function(students); // no need for address operator & here
}

int main()
{
    char **students = malloc(sizeof *students); // room for 1 char *
    students[0] = malloc(sizeof *students[0]);  // room for 1 char
    a_function(&students);
}
```

So, we don't need more than three `*` anywhere here.

---

When you had `ANOTHER_function(char ****students)` and therein

```
    *students = (char**)realloc(*students, 2 * sizeof(char*));
```

the type of `*students` was `char ***` and didn't match the `(char**)` on the right - fortunately, because `*students` was the address of `main`'s `students` instead of its value.

```
    **students = (char**)realloc(**students, 2 * sizeof(char*));
```

was correct (albeit overly complicated) in this case; the corresponding `malloc()` for the new element would have been

```
    (**students)[1] = malloc(sizeof *(**students)[1]);
```